# ReactJS get response undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest, axios

I have a code that sends data to the server and I have a function

```
save(contentType, data, setResponse) {
    axios({
        method: 'POST',
        data: data,
    }).then((response) => {
        setResponse(data.response);
}
```

That gives me type undefined. How can I fix this?

Comment: Try `response.data` instead of `data.response`

Comment: Thanks very much, it worked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're supposed to write `response.data` instead of `data.response` as the variable there is `response` not `data`:

```
submitForm(contentType, data, setResponse) {
    axios({
        url: `${API_BASE_URL}`,
        method: 'POST',
        data: data,
    }).then((response) => {
        // Change it here...
        setResponse(response.data);
    }).catch((error) => {
        setResponse(error.response);
    })
}
```